# Search for substring in entire dataframe and if substring is found print next row to the searched substring

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe `df` (read from an excel sheet) with over 3000s rows. I want to search a string in `df` which has occured more than 50 times in `df` and I want to print the next row (only one) to the row in which my searched string is found (substring). It means that it should print next single row/line which is present just after the row in which my substring/searched string is found.

I've tried:

```
df=pd.read_excel(sample.xlsx)
substring="Size of file is:"
df[df.apply(lambda row:row.astype(str).str.contains(substring,case=False).any(),axis=1)]
```

This returns the searched string which is `'Size of file is'`. But I want to print the next single row/line wherever my searched string is found in the whole data.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with `fill_value=False`:

```
np.random.seed(2000)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(['aa','abs','abdf','abg'], size=(10, 3)))
print (df)
      0     1     2
0  abdf    aa  abdf
1   abs  abdf   abg
2    aa    aa    aa
3  abdf   abg  abdf
4    aa   abg   abg
5  abdf   abg   abs
6  abdf    aa  abdf
7   abg   abg   abs
8   abs    aa   abg
9    aa    aa  abdf

substring = 'abd'
df1 = df[df.apply(lambda row:row.astype(str).str.contains(substring,case=False).any(),axis=1).shift(fill_value=False)]
print (df1)
      0     1     2
1   abs  abdf   abg
2    aa    aa    aa
4    aa   abg   abg
6  abdf    aa  abdf
7   abg   abg   abs
```

Similar solution:

```
df1 = df[df.apply(lambda col:col.astype(str).str.contains(substring,case=False)).any(axis=1).shift(fill_value=False)]
print (df1)
      0     1     2
1   abs  abdf   abg
2    aa    aa    aa
4    aa   abg   abg
6  abdf    aa  abdf
7   abg   abg   abs
```

Answer (score 0):

use vectorized calculations :

```
df.iloc[1:df[df['column_serch'].str.contains('substring')].index.values[0]]
```